# Spring boot performance problems

Tags: spring, angular, http, tomcat, spring-boot

We have a web application with a spring boot back-end running on an embedded tomcat and an angular 4 front-end (httpd server), and we noticed that after every deployment (we're using jenkins) there is a major performance problem, and even if we stopped httpd for the front , the back-end always receives queries from active sessions, which makes the startup super slow.

Any hints or ideas on how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: is it only the startup which is slow or the service in itself is slow?

Comment: the service itself, and it stays that way for more than 5 hours !